# Extra Characters getting added in C++ for char array data type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code, where the booking_id is calculated using a function.

```
void calculateBookingID(char* id);
class BookFlight
{
public:
    char booking_id[5];
    void addBooking()
    {
        string dummy;
        calculateBookingID(booking_id);
        cout << "Enter Airline ID : ";
        cin.getline(airline_id,3);             

    }
    void displayBooking()
    {       
            cout << booking_id <<'\t'<<airline_id<<endl;       
    }

private:
    char airline_id[3];

} b1,b2;

string getNextBookingID(string ID);

int main()
{
    b1.addBooking();
    b1.displayBooking();
    return 0; 
}

void calculateBookingID(char* id)
{  
        strcpy(id,"B1001");
}
```

For some reason in the booking_id the airline_id is also getting added. In the debugger the values look fine, but while displaying it adds 2 extra characters.

Example output:

```
B1001CD CD
```

Here the booking_id is B1001CD, where as it should be B1001

I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Can someonce please advise what have I done wrong?
Regards, Abinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have figured it out changing the `booking_id` to `char booking_id[6]` will fix your current problem. However consider the following points for improvement in your code:

1. Make the fields `booking_id` and `airline_id` reasonably big enough like `100` chars to accommodate error handling. It will be much better if you can make them dynamic as well.
2. Make `booking_id` private
3. Make `calculateBookingID()` a private class method. Try avoiding free functions while coding in C++
4. Use [strcpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s) instead of `strcpy` as the later is depricated.
5. Avoid global scope objects, instead create `b1 and b2` inside `main()` where you need them.

Comment: Note that `strcpy_s` is either Microsoft specific, or C11 specific. [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is the way to go if C11 is not targeted.

Comment: Thanks Sisir for your comments. Point 2 and 3 are taken care. I took the parts from a bigger program and posted it for getting an opinion.

Comment: @Victor "to accommodate error handling" - `airline_id` is taken from cin. So if it allows only 6 characters and the user enters more than that then there will be buffer-overflow and it will override the null terminator which will lead to a further series of problems. So to avoid that the buffer can be made a little extra-large to accommodate such issues.

Comment: @Sisir I totally aggree with increasing the size of the buffer to accommodate the `NUL` character. However, can't buffer overflow be avoided by using `std::basic_istream::get`, `std::basic_istream::read`, or `std::basic_istream::getline`?

Comment: @Victor Even with these APIs how will we ensure the buffer allocated to store the string is sufficient? e.g. with `getline` how will we know before-hand what will be length of the line

Answer (score 0):

Got it, booking_id needs to be of 6 characters to accomodate the null.

Thanks, Abinash